# Pass State params using URL Routing to a new tab in AngularJS without showing up in the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, routeparams

I am using AngularJS with ui-router. I am trying to pass the parameters to a new tab. So I am passing the params from the state to controller without showing up in the URL. I am using the Params of `$state.href` like so:

In js file,

```
var paramValues = { 'path': true, 'logoValue': 123};
var achiveRoute = $state.href('state123', paramValues);
$window.open(achiveRoute, '_blank');
```

In state file,

```
.state("state123", {
    url: "/sessiontimeline",
    templateUrl: /partials/session.html,
    params : { 'path': true, 'logoValue': null }
}
```

I am trying to access these params in the controller using `StateParams`.

```
var logoValue = $stateParams.logoValue;
```

But `logoValue` is showing `undefined`.

How do I set/read the path parameters from the route?

Comment: Can you show the controller where you are using `var logoValue = $StateParams.logoValue;`? Specifically, let's see what you're injecting in that controller.

Comment: Here is the controller.    

module.controller('sessionCtrl', [
            '$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
            function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

Comment: You're injecting `$stateParams`, but then you're trying to access it with a capital "S" (`$StateParams.logoValue`). That is likely causing your `undefined` issue.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. I am using small "S". That was a typo. Sorry.
var logoValue = $stateParams.logoValue;

Comment: If you `console.log(achiveRoute)` just before your `$window.open()` call, what is the value?

Comment: #/sessiontimeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass those parameters on the querystring, you have to define your route such that it will accept them on the querystring. What's happening right now is that you don't have a state defined with a URL that accepts parameters on the querystring, so it is using the defaults that you have specified in your state (`true` for `path` and `null` for `logoValue`). Here's how you should define your state to accept those parameters on the querystring:

```
.state("state123", {
    url: "/sessiontimeline?path?logoValue",
    templateUrl: /partials/session.html,
    params : { 'path': true, 'logoValue': null }
}
```

With the above configuration you can pass the parameters either directly through a `$state.go` call or via the querystring and your `$state.href('state123', paramValues)` should output `/sessiontimeline?path=true&logoValue=123`.

Comment: Yes, we can pass through URL using querystring but my question is to pass the parameters without mentioning in the URL. That's the reason I am using params to pass the value. Is there any other way to pass?

Comment: If you want to open a new window and pass parameters through routing you have to use the querystring. If you don’t want to do that, you will have to use something like local storage.